# Insect Identification question: Is this a flea? If yes, what kind?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in the pacific northwest and I found these insects in the carpet and comforter. I suspect them to be flea based on my image search. But I would like to confirm. Can you also tell me what kind of flea is this?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgUNh.png) [image: flea picture 1]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plyPe.png) [image: flea picture 2]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJxts.png) [image: flea picture 3]

My apologies for the grainy pictures. These are my attempts at capturing the photo from the microscope's eye piece using my smart phone.

Comment: This may be indistinguishable, thus better images may need to be taken.

Comment: It does look very much like a flea though.